# Kernel dying repeatedly

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, data-mining, ubuntu-16.04

I am using jupyter notebook to implement a binary classifier in Python. Data I am using consists of 100000 tuples. It is working fine on my laptop.

But when i switched to a desktop computer, clicking on run all cells in jupyter notebook says "Kernel died and will restart automatically".

OS in the desktop is Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using Python 2.7. I am not using anaconda or any other packages like this.

Other Python libraries I am using are-
Pandas,
Numpy,
Scipy,
Scikit-learn,
Matplotlib,
Graphlab create

Here is the code it is failing on-

```
def find_nearest(mat):
    my_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=ds_original.columns)
    ll=range(mat.shape[0])
    for i in ll:
        tt=query(mat[i], model, k=10, max_search_radius=3)
        my_dataframe=my_dataframe.append(tt,ignore_index=True)
    return my_dataframe



start=time.time()
ds_original_null=ds_original[ds_original.isnull().any(axis=1)]
ds_original_not_null=ds_original.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
temp=ds_original_null.copy()
temp[cat_columns]=temp[cat_columns].apply(lambda x:x.astype('category'))
temp[cat_columns] = temp[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
temp=temp.fillna(0)
numpyMatrix_null = temp.as_matrix()
sparseMatrix_null=sparse.csr_matrix(numpyMatrix_null)
nearest_tuples=find_nearest(sparseMatrix_null)
ds_original_null=ds_original_null.reset_index()
ds_original_null=ds_original_null.drop('index',axis=1)
ds_original_null=ds_original_null.combine_first(nearest_tuples)
ds=ds_original_null.append(ds_original_not_null)
end=time.time()
print end-start
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to be a minimum verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It looks like your question is just that the kernel is crashing on one of your systems and not the other and has nothing to do with how many tuples you have to check

Comment: have you tried running just one cell at a time? What about a minimal test cell (foo = 1+1)? Are you using the range() function?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I tried running just one cell at a time. It works when I run cells one by one. I don't know about minimal test cell. And yes I am using range() function.

Comment: Hmm... if one cell at a time is working don't worry about the minimal test. Can you give a paste of the cell it fails on? in python2 range() makes a full list of all the numbers. So range(sys.maxint) will utilize 64 gb of system memory (RAM) though I would normally expect this to crash your computer I'm not sure if ipython crashes the kernel to save the rest of your system. Generally using xrange() is a better option as it's a generator.

Comment: what do you get for mat.shape[0]? Can you either break it up into multiple cells or use a debugger to step through it and see exactly what line you're crashing on?

Comment: Thanks for replying. mat.shape[0] is inside the function definition. how can i break the function definition? i am using it to get the number of rows in mat sparse matrix. and can you tell me how to use debugger?

Comment: you can put a print(mat.shape[0]) right before the actual line executes or use a debugger. A debugger is an external program, usually part of an IDE (spyder, pycharm, canopy, etc) that lets you set breakpoints or run your code line by line and view the variables as you go. When you want to learn to use a proper debugger I would recommend looking up tutorials and tutorial videos. For now try just using a print either in the function or just before you call it.

Comment: Check the *console* output. Does it show the error? Break the cell into multiple to see where exactly you e.g. run out of memory.